# How can I use PHP and Lightbox to add captions to the images on my site?

Tags: php, html, lightbox

I'm still quite a beginner to PHP so hang with me here..

I've created an (almost recursive) PHP script that looks inside an image directory and its child 'thumbnail' directory. It then creates a loop to select each image and its corresponding thumbnail, generate a link from that thumb and then move on to image #2.

Here is the code for the function I am using:

```
function imageroll ($imgnum, $album) 
{
$i=1;

while($i<=$imgnum)  
  {
  $ii = str_pad($i, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
  echo "<a class=\"thumb\" href=\"pictures/", $album, "_", $ii, ".jpg\" rel=\"lightbox[", $album, "]\">";
  echo "<img src=\"pictures/thumbs/thumb-", $album, "_", $ii, ".jpg\" \/ >";
  echo "</a>";
  $i++;
  }
}
```

**My question, then, is how would I modify this script so that I can use the caption function of Lightbox?**

To do this, I would need to add the `title` attribute to each image inside the `<a>` tag with a string captioning each photo. How can I introduce adding $title to the loop without having to pass 12 different $titles to the function?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick comment: what about using a for cycle? It looks a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I introduce adding $title to
>   the loop without having to pass 12
>   different $titles to the function?

Use an array, that's why they exists. Add your titles to a $titles array and use $title[$i] for accessing each title.

For more information on PHP arrays, check http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and consult with any good PHP books out there.

Comment: Perfect- I've got a hard coded array doing this. I am curious- is it possible to assign the array from an external source, say, a text document? The idea is to make the captions as modular as possible without having to code in the array each time I want to use this function with a bunch of images.

Comment: @CaseyHunt Maybe the most elegant solution would be to develop an interface for captioning the pictures (just think about any serious gallery on the web - Flickr, Picasa, etc. you name it) and store the captions in a database.

Probably you'll have to learn quite a bit of PHP (and MySQL for example) to achieve this, but it really worth the effort! In the long run, perhaps most of your website data will be stored in database, so learn how to use it well.

Comment: I agree- learning MySQL is on the horizon for me but not for this project. What I've ended up doing is creating a padded array where it pads the array equal to `$imgnum`. This seems to be working well enough. From where I call the function, I can assign specific array entries captions- these correspond to the images I wish to caption.

Answer (score 0):

Usually lightboxes use  title to display captions, so try this:

```
  echo "<a class=\"thumb\" title=\"" . $title . "\" href=\"pictures/", $album, "_", $ii, ".jpg\" rel=\"lightbox[", $album, "]\">";
  echo "<img src=\"pictures/thumbs/thumb-", $album, "_", $ii, ".jpg\" \/ >";
  echo "</a>";
```

Let me know if that helps

Comment: Yes, using title is a function of lightbox and I see you've assigned it the $title variable. However the question still stands- I am using a loop to display a series of images. How can I then incorporate a number of different "titles" in that loop without having to pass many different $titles to the function?

Answer (score 0):

you can use face-box as a lightbox and insert caption thru it.